# I'm creating a blur on applicationDidEnterBackground how can I then delete this blur

Tags: ios, swift

Im creating a blur in my ios app every time you send the app to background. This is what I'm using right now:

```
var topController : UIViewController = (application.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!
while ((topController.presentedViewController) != nil)
{    
    topController = topController.presentedViewController!
}

if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()
{
    topController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let blurEffect     = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

    // Always fill the view
    blurEffectView.frame            = topController.view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    topController.view.addSubview(blurEffectView) //if you have more UIViews, use an insertSubview API to place it where needed
} 
else
{
    topController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

My question is. Is there a way I can delete this blur in another viewcontroller (which is inside a tabbarcontroller)?

**EDIT:** I need to delete the blur in another viewcontroller because my user needs to enter a password and if it is correct it'll delete the blur.

Comment: Why not remove it in the `applicationWillEnterForeground` method?

Comment: Because the user needs to put a password and if the password is correct it needs to delete the blur.

Comment: Than in the applicationWillEnterForegeound you can present a view contontroller and ask for the password